# reading outlook mailbox and get two consecutive email having same subject

Tags: python, win32com

iam trying to read an outlook mailbox and select two consecutive(today and yesterday) emails which have a given subject line.

have been able to get the first email correctly but second(immediately previous day email) email is not getting in output. Instead some random email is getting printed.

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
import os

outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").\n
GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 
messages=inbox.Items
message=messages.GetLast()
for message in messages:
    if message.Subject=="FW: Open orders with 15 day outstanding":
       H = message.Body
       message = messages.GetPrevious()
       H1 = message.Body
```

the expected output is that H= todays email and H1 = yesterday email, both having the given subject.

the actual output is that H = todays email but H1 = some random email in inbox

Comment: have you tried, sorting it by "Recieved Time" and then finding it

Comment: Also ,`It returns Nothing if no previous object exists, for example, if already positioned at the beginning of the collection. To ensure correct operation of the GetFirst, GetLast, GetNext, and GetPrevious methods in a large collection, call GetFirst before calling GetNext on that collection, and call GetLast before calling GetPrevious. To ensure that you are always making the calls on the same collection, create an explicit variable that refers to that collection before entering the loop`

Comment: have tried using, messages.Sort("ReceivedTime", False). but this also does not changes H1 output. the mailbox is already reverse sorted and iam calling Getlast first (H) and then trying to call previous item(H1).